# нужна ли запятая, обоснование

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

И если на скалах разбивался корабль, и из него вымывало груз, он вместе со всеми плыл собирать его.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли первая запятая (после "корабль"), и почему. 
Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*И если на скалах разбивался корабль и из него вымывало груз, он вместе со всеми плыл собирать его.*

Если придаточные предложения связаны однородным подчинением, запятая перед одиночным союзом И не ставится. Здесь первую И нельзя считать повторяющимся союзом, т.к. это усилительная частица, она относится к обоим придаточным.( если = - ) и ( = ), [- =]. Если бы это был повторяющийся союз, то и подчинительный союз если тоже повторился бы.